# Discord.js having trouble with args in cases

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having trouble getting my command to register more than 1 argument but it doesn't seem to want to work anyway I put it and it isn't giving off errors it will just go to the default case if the arguments are more than one. it worked when I had it args1 = args[1] but I am now trying to incorporate spacing in some arguments and it falls short there.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const util = require('../../Util/utils');
const trickarray = require (`../../json/broomtricks`);

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    let mention = message.mentions.users.first();
    let london = "london";
    let godricshollow = "godrics hollow";
    let ministry = "ministry of magic";
    //Code Start

    let opt = args.shift(` `).toLowerCase()

    let itemName = "broomstick";

    let userDB = bot.db.get(message.author.id)

    let item = bot.config.shop[itemName]
    if(!item || !userDB.inv.some(i => i.name == itemName)){
        message.channel.send(bot.embed(`You don't have a broomstick`))
    }else{



       
        switch(opt[0]){

            case 'travel':
                 switch (opt[1]){
                     case 'london':
                        bot.db.set(`${message.author.id}.location`, london)
                        message.channel.send(bot.embed(`${message.author} Used their broomstick to travel to london.`))
                        console.log(`${message.author.username} travelled to ${userDB.location} using their broomstick.`)
                        break;
                     
                     case 'godrics':
                        bot.db.set(`${message.author.id}.location`, godricshollow)
                        message.channel.send(bot.embed(`${message.author} Used their broomstick to travel to godrics hollow.`))
                        console.log(`${message.author.username} travelled to ${userDB.location} using their broomstick.`)
                        break;
                     case 'ministry':
                         bot.db.set(`${message.author.id}.location`, ministry)
                         message.channel.send(bot.embed(`${message.author} Used their broomstick to travel to the Ministry Of Magic.`))
                         console.log(`${message.author.username} travelled to ${userDB.location} using their broomstick.`)
                         break;                 
                     default:
                         message.channel.send(bot.embed(`london | godrics hollow | Ministry of Magic`))
                         break;

                }

            break;

            case 'race':
                let flip = Math.floor(Math.random(1 * 101))
                switch(!mention){
                      case flip > 51:
                        message.channel.send(bot.embed(`You race ${mention || `a random`} and placed **1st**`))
                        break;

                      case flip < 50:
                        message.channel.send(bot.embed(`You race ${mention || `a random`} and placed **last**`))
                        break;

                };
                break;
            case 'trick':
                let trick = util.dynamicgenerator(trickarray);
                message.channel.send(`You decide to do a trick on your broom you do a **${trick}**.`)
                break;
            

            
        default:
            message.channel.send(bot.embed(`>broomstick travel | race | trick  `))
          
        
             }
            }

    
    //Code End

}
```

is there another way to format the "opt[1]" any help appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) docs:

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

So what you are doing with `opt[0]` is accessing the first character of a string, instead of the first value of an array. In addition, adding a string with a space as argument to the `shift` method does nothing. You can remove the `opt` part and just do `switch(args[0].toLowerCase()) {` directly.